# remove this useless assignment to local variable c#

Tags: c#, lint, sonarlint

```
var  stopFyon = new StopFYON();
IEnumerable<CarOnline> carOnlineData = (IEnumerable<CarOnline>)vehrep.GetCarOnlineDetail(maintainStopFactoryOrderNo.VehicleDetail).Result;

if (carOnlineData.Any())
{
    stopFyon = vehtran.CreateStopFactoryOrderNo(carOnlineData, maintainStopFactoryOrderNo, lastUpdatedBy);
}
else
{
    stopFyon = vehtran.CreateStopFactoryOrderNo(null, maintainStopFactoryOrderNo, lastUpdatedBy);
}
return gen.GetResponse((Int16)ResultCode.Success, (Int16)MsgType.Ok, null, vehrep.StopFactoryOrderNo(stopFyon));
```

I got warning error when using sonar code analysis:

> remove this useless assignment to local variable `stopFyon`

Comment: `StopFYON stopFyon;`? you don't need to assign a new instance because in the if/else you always assign a new value to it overwriting it.

Comment: So How can I create a global variable for this?

Comment: @RameshRajendran just look at the first comment

Comment: By not using `var` if you give it a value of the expected type. or of a parentclass/interface type that the StopFYON inherits of you can declare it anywhere without the need to use `var`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `var`:

```
StopFYON stopFyon;
```

The reason for the warning is that you initialize the variable with the default constructor(which could theoretically be a very expensive call, at least it's confusing). But this assignment gets overridden in all branches(the `if` and the `else`). So it's useless.

If you would use `stopFyon` before the `if` the warning would also disappear.

Comment: But why it's not showing an error while am giving `StopFYON stopFyon = null`?? this is also a useless assignment.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: you're right. But that costs nothing. You don't create an instance which you don't use. The warning is not about unassigned variables but about useless instances. It wants to protect you from careless mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The message is pretty straightforward:

```
IEnumerable<CarOnline> carOnlineData = (IEnumerable<CarOnline>)vehrep.GetCarOnlineDetail(maintainStopFactoryOrderNo.VehicleDetail).Result;

StopFYON stopFyon;

if (carOnlineData.Any())
    stopFyon = vehtran.CreateStopFactoryOrderNo(carOnlineData, maintainStopFactoryOrderNo, lastUpdatedBy);
else
    stopFyon = vehtran.CreateStopFactoryOrderNo(null, maintainStopFactoryOrderNo, lastUpdatedBy);
```

The first assignment:

```
var stopFyon = new StopFYON();
```

is useless since another assignment is performed within the `if statement` right after.

Comment: But why it's not showing an error while am giving `StopFYON stopFyon = null`?? this is also a useless assignment

Comment: Because you initialize your variable with `null`. A `null` assignment is not expensive; the assignment that uses a constructor, on the opposite, could be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It is working, when I change the code `StopFYON stopFyon = null` instead of `var  stopFyon = new StopFYON();`

Comment: `= Null` don't think you need that part since it should default to null. `StopFYON stopFyon;` should suffice.

Comment: @Dragonvil . Yeah! That's better than me. But don't know why it's not showing an error while am giving `StopFYON stopFyon = null`?? this is also a useless assignment?

Answer (score 1):

just assign the type using `StopFYON stopFyon;` no need to initialize as your if condition blocks are assigning the actual values.