# Remove this useless assignment to local variable - sonarqube - using try catch

Tags: c#, sonarqube

In the following code, sonarqube is complaining for the mentioned error in the question:

```
   public async static Task<T> StartReadAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {
        T result = default;
        using (await _lock.ReadLockAsync(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            _logger.Info("read lock acquired.");
            try
            {
                result = await func();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"exception occured while read: {ex}");
            }
        }
        _logger.Info("read lock released.");
        return result;
    }
```

How can I re-write this code to resolve this complain from sonarqube?

Comment: Does your catch block rethrow? Can you provide a [mcve] example rather then just commented bits?

Comment: @Jon I have provided the exact code.

Comment: Have you tried not having a `result` at all and doing a `return await func()` / `return default(T)` instead?

Comment: I could assume that it's complaining about `T result = default;` but why are you making me guess?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: How is it redundant? If `func()` throws an exception or the task it returns throws an exception, there'd be no value in `result`. Without the initial assignment, the variable isn't definitely assigned at the `return` statement.

Comment: I *suspect* this is a sonarqube false positive. I'd be willing to look with an actual [mcve] that I can copy/paste/try, but I don't want to have to set up a bunch of other things in order to reproduce it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove this useless assignment to local variable c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903201/remove-this-useless-assignment-to-local-variable-c-sharp)

Comment: @Jon I will try to provide a complete console program

Comment: @PWND: No, because in that case the assignment *was* redundant - in this case I don't think it is.

Comment: @CaiusJard answer looks one solution to me. I am trying for that.

Comment: `default(T)` could probably also be simplified to `default`..

Comment: Maybe it's asking to only declare `T result` instead of declaring and assigning and only do the default assignment in the `catch` since it's unneeded in the normal flow: `result = default`